# Infinite scroll for dynamic div posts, without pagination

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

We have dynamic posts like **Facebook wall without pagination**.
we have browsed a lot but couldn't find infinite scroll for that div posts.

is there any method or plugins that can load 10 posts in a container or for every 1500pixels of height.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. http://jscroll.com/

I think lazyscroll is what you are looking for.

UPDATE: you need to set the padding option. remember its padding from bottom. 
https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll#usage

See here how to use padding.

Comment: how to configure that for certain height in pixels for every load??

Answer (score 0):

jScroll still requires that your page contains pagination links, which are specified using the nextSelector option.